# Find leaks with AS 3.0 profiler

Tags: android, android-studio, memory-leaks, profiling

I'm trying to wrap my head around memory leaks and how to detect them in my code without the use of the library `leakcanary`but rather observing the profiler embedded in Android Studio 3

I just created a new "Hello world" project and launched it on my device, I clicked on the **memory** tab in the profiler and pressed **record memory allocation**, rotated it a few times and checked the result

I got this graph here

[image: memory allocation for basic hello world app]

What I would like to know is why do I have 4 allocation of MainActivity still in memory? 
I created one for every rotation but shouldn't they be stopped and garbage collected?
Perhaps that is not the way to find if a memory leak occurs but I'd like to know how to